# Passing data with request using Akka http

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-http

I am new to Scala/Akka and I have a service that I want to call using Akka Scaladsl. Using curl, I can call the service like this:

```
curl -v -d "STRING_DATA" -X GET http://localhost:3838/query?format=json
```

I know I can call the service like this using Scaladsl:

```
Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:3838/query?format=json"))
responseFuture onComplete {
    case Success(response) => {
        // Do something with the response here..
    }
}
```

I am not sure how I can pass the "data" ("STRING_DATA") along with the request through `HttpRequest`. Thoughts?

Comment: How about passing the data with the url: `HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:3838/query?format=json&data=STRING_DATA")`

Comment: @RobertUdah did that, but it would not work.. it does not see it as "raw data" for the request body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl -v -d "STRING_DATA" -X GET http://localhost:3838/query?format=json
```

The above command makes a GET request with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type (if you left out the `-X GET`, the command would be a POST because of the `-d` parameter). Using [`FormData`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/FormData$.html) is one way to model `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data in Akka HTTP:

```
val ent = FormData(Map("format" -> "json", "data" -> "STRING_DATA")).toEntity
```

To send a POST request with that data:

```
Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST,
    uri = "http://localhost:3838/query", entity = ent))
```

To send a GET request:

```
Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:3838/query", entity = ent))
```